# What can an attacker do if they find positive results for `haveibeenpwned`?

Tags: have-i-been-pwned

I know maltego has a `haveibeenpwned` module/transform. Assuming an attacker ran a bunch of emails through that module and got a few positive hits for `haveibeenpwned`, what can be done with those results? If the attacker is a white hat pentester, I can't imagine anything special to do with the email since the leaked data shouldn't be on the open internet. Even if such data got uploaded, they should be taken down sooner or later by some authorities. In the case of a malicious attacker, however, I suppose one can buy the leaked data on the dark web.

Am I correct in my assumptions? What can be done with `haveibeenpwned` results, as a white hat & a black hat?

Comment: LOL you really have an idealistic idea of how the internet works. In the "dark web" there are forums where people sell breach data like password hashes (what do you think where most of the data haveibeenpwned uses come from?). And taking down an dark web / onion web site only accessible through TOR is pretty difficult as you don't know where the actual server is located.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that can be done with that data, that's why it's available for people to check if they were breached so they can act ASAP.

Two of the main things an attacker can potentially do are the following:

1. Phishing - An attacker can see that his victim is using a specific application and craft a spear phishing attack.
2. Breached Passwords - While there are a lot of efforts to remove breaches from the internet, it's very hard to get them fully removed. Unfortunately, most of them are accessible really easily by anyone if they just look for it.

So yes, there is a lot someone can do with the knowledge of knowing someone was breached with a specific application.